# Google Cloud name server holding my domain name 'hostage'?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I have created a Cloud DNS Zone for the domain name cachevalleyaa.org.  The zone NS record set tells me the name server is ns-cloud-a#.googledomains.com - the 'A' name servers.

BUT, NS record query using the online Dig tool tells me cachevalleyaa.org name server is ns-cloud-e#.googledomains.com - the 'E' name servers.

In addition:

"nslookup cachevalleyaa.org ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com" returns:

- Server: Unknown
- Address: 216.239.32.106
- Name: cachevalleyaa.org
- Address: 34.83.206.184

"nslookup cachevalleyaa.org ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com" returns:

- Server: Unknown
- Address: 216.239.32.110
- Name: cachevalleyaa.org
- *where is the address? and why is there still a record here?*

Some questions

- Is something stuck or so I just need to be more patient?
- Is there a way to clear the record set in the E name servers?
- Do I need to hire someone, or subscribe to support, to get this resolved?
- Is my domain name simply lost?  Maybe move to a different name?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a caching issue, it should clear up with time. I don't know how "ns-cloud-e*[1-4]*.googledomains.com" is showing up as an NS record for you. Was that the original NS record before you migrated to the new one? If that is the case, you will see the e* NS records till the TTL for that record expires and remote name servers pick up your new NS records.

I did several dns traces, all i see is the ns-cloud-a*[1-4]* ones.

Here is the dig trace from my laptop using one of the root name servers 198.41.0.0 -

```
$ dig +trace cachevalleyaa.org @198.41.0.4 +nodnssec


.           518400  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           518400  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.

org.            172800  IN  NS  a0.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            172800  IN  NS  a2.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            172800  IN  NS  b0.org.afilias-nst.org.
org.            172800  IN  NS  b2.org.afilias-nst.org.
org.            172800  IN  NS  c0.org.afilias-nst.info.
org.            172800  IN  NS  d0.org.afilias-nst.org.

cachevalleyaa.org.  86400   IN  NS  ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com.
cachevalleyaa.org.  86400   IN  NS  ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com.
cachevalleyaa.org.  86400   IN  NS  ns-cloud-a3.googledomains.com.
cachevalleyaa.org.  86400   IN  NS  ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com.

cachevalleyaa.org.  300 IN  A   34.83.206.184
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. I found the A name server result using another computer.

After some more research I found my Google Domains DNS page under "Name Servers" under "Use the Google Domain name servers" lists all of the 'E' name servers.

Are we fighting ourselves here? I only bought the domain to use it on GCP.  How to I tell Google Domains to back off?

Comment: Is Google your domain registrar for cachevalleyaa.org? if so, do you see the A record under "Custom resource records" under the domain configuration page?

Comment: I bought the domain from Google.  Honestly do not know if it is the registrar - sure seems like it wants to be. Not sure what is the right way to do this so i can use the domain on GCP.  And no, there are no "Custom resource records"

Comment: The registrar has the authoritative name servers. Follow the instructions on this link to see the dns records for you domain - https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9211383?hl=en

Comment: So I should not create a DNS zone in Cloud DNS?

Comment: No. What you add in Cloud DNS might not be visible to outside world. If you want to expose the dns records in Cloud DNS to the outside world, your name servers(NS records) in your domain registrar have to match with the NS records in Cloud DNS.

Comment: Are you able to login to https://domains.google.com/ and see your domain there?

Comment: A little bit confused about that link.  In Google Cloud they have us create two A records, one for cachevalleyaa.org the other for www.cachevalley.org. The data in both is the static IP address. Should I create two A records? Do I need a CNAME record too?

Comment: if it is the same IP, you can CNAME www to the primary domain